# Can I have an audio stream that plays continuously regardless of what user is logged in?

Tags: audio, music, user-account, root

(I suspect the short answer is "no," but I wanted to make sure.)

I have two accounts on my MBA (work and personal). During the work day, the computer is also playing my music. When I need to switch to the personal account for something, the music stops (iTunes actually pauses itself, but other players that don't pause also lose the ability to generate audio output).

Is there any way to "get root" on the audio output, so to speak, so that I can have audio playing regardless of which account I'm logged into?

(I realize this presents some UI conundrums as well because it's unlikely that a process running with sufficient privileges could easily present itself as a normal app. But if it has to be a background daemon that I control via shell scripts, so be it!)